# I'm having a problem passing an argument to a function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, quasar

I'm new to Typescript and I'm having trouble passing arguments to a function in Typescript. This function is called when I render a form modal.But I end up getting two errors:

> "Argument of type 'Promise<AxiosResponse>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(data: Record<string, unknown>) => Promise'."
>
> "Type 'Promise<AxiosResponse>' provides no match for the signature '(data: Record<string, unknown>): Promise'."

```
  function openModal(activity) {
    const data = ref({
      name: activity.name,
    })     

    formRender.render(activity, updateActivity(activity.id,{name:data.value.name}))
  }
```

This would be the function:

```
export function updateActivity(id: number, data: Record<string, unknown>) {
 return http.patch(`/${id}`, { name: data.name })
}
```

FormRender:

```
 export function FormRender<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(formName: string) {
  return {
   render(formAttributes: T | Record<string, unknown>, service: (data: T) => Promise<unknown>) {
     dialog({
      component: FormRender,
      componentProps: {
        formName,
        formAttributes,
        service
     },
  })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export function updateActivity(id: number, data: Record<string, unknown>) {
 return http.patch(`/${id}`, { name: data.name })
}
```

This function returns `Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>>`. It's an `async` function which means you'll have to `await` the result to get the value returned from the HTTP request.

To get the data out of this type you must first await it, and then fetch the `data` property of the axios response:

```
export async function updateActivity(id: number, data: Record<string, unknown>) {
  const response = await http.patch(`/${id}`, { name: data.name })
  return response.data // This may require a JSON.parse or further prep depending on what the API returns
}
```

Now since the `service` argument is typed as a function, you should be able to pass a function that calls this method:

```
formRender.render(activity, (data) => updateActivity(activity.id, {name:data.value.name}))
```

[Here's a working example with no type errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBACxjMcBmUIjgcgIYAewEAzjgFDkCmBksceJAngHYDG6AruzMS3JzAATPDCoBBNrwBuwGEwAUwIQC44LTiABGVKABo4ImHjUAlKm2hCAPCRhRgLAOYHuAaxYQA7iwB8ASjUABUwQYBIqa3NLKBs7B2dXFg9vP184AG9yODhLFjs4KCoSSHyqOABeBi88OURkMAA6MFE2BAUAAwB6ABIM5QBfDoMM9TwQKjUjPEaWcfKB-2zCqhhOKH4ikogyxum4Lq64ABUEcLgQPCYVgEdOYC2GOAApAGUAeQA5ZrwoCLhoFxYAhdHAwEVUEIqGAqCwhI4nAD+F4EKI4DAQXBxEEAJIrNYbEjkAaUGh0eBobhSPhwABi0BA5jhumsxzgNDEcJIcGiVls9gRSRSPl8vgUaAZn3maniCP8mWWRQJ-CyORyRWZUHFDPEyAcWk4YhIajZAB8eRY+bLEgJkp4RQYIlBZGxJnAFNMTfKKukQlhwpF3Pa-PLVWqcodGlHljkSbHiZQ8gU8NTZPJKpk4Mo1ABGABMAGYDNI8AAbThu0ZzCZqfAkIRoHADOAkpMUhlMqFQDP0qCM2Fd6zyGEQNAMVNyJhinAkLBUXsgKUTHBLcgSvud3SNDVdhQpmSTgwe0R4b3pQRGCQT+R769MRrKEbVybTRol8tUWbzRZLIA)

Comment: Hello Alex. Thank you so much for answering me, I've been stuck on this for days.
But, two errors occurred when using  'formRender.render(activity, await updateActivity(activity.id, {name:data.value.name}))'

Are they:
"'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules."

"Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type '(data: Record<string, unknown>) => Promise<unknown>'."

Again, thanks for answering me.

Comment: Explaining the nuances of async programming is a bit much for this comment, but it sounds you should do [some reading up](https://www.google.com/search?q=async+await+js&oq=async+await+js&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.2319j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on that. Also I just noticed that `service` is a function, which changes things... I've updated my answer.